# fiddler composer authenticating a request

Tags: http, authentication, fiddler

this might seem silly, but here is my issue.
If I make a call to this authenticate url like this:

[image: Moltin success]

Everything works fine, but I want to send the body as JSON.
So I tried this:

[image: Moltin failed]

And this failed, with the error:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "exception": "invalid_request",
    "error": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"grant_type\" parameter."
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly note, the Accept header is used by HTTP clients to tell the server what content types they'll accept. The server will then send back a response, which will include a Content-Type header telling the client what the content type of the returned content actually is.

However, as you may have noticed, HTTP requests can also contain Content-Type headers. Why? Well, think about POST or PUT requests. With those request types, the client is actually sending a bunch of data to the server as part of the request, and the Content-Type header tells the server what the data actually is (and thus determines how the server will parse it).

In particular, for a typical POST request resulting from an HTML form submission, the Content-Type of the request will normally be either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data.

Comment: Is that a guess or can you tell somehow?

Comment: you can research on content body type and http headers.